# Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git ls-remote -h ***public github url *** HEAD

Tags: git, jenkins, devops, cicd, jenkins-git-plugin

I have installed jenkins on ec2 instance. when i try to configure my public github repo with the ec2 instance then it throwing the **error:** *Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git ls-remote -h ***public github url *** HEAD*
[image]

I reinstalled the git plugin as well but it won't work. I added credentials as well(hope not required for public git repo). Any possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed [Git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-client/) in Jenkins?

Comment: yes Git Plugin is installed in Jenkins

Comment: @Andy this could be a connectivity issue as well then. Have you tried accessing Github from EC2 Instance itself? Are there any firewalls blocking the connectivity?

Comment: yes I got the answer. I haven't installed the git over my ec2 instance. Once I installed it then the error gone. thanks @ycr